# JavaScript: parseFloat() strips trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, floating-point, precision

I have been trying to find a solution to the following problem. I have a string that is a floating-point number like,

```
 var value = '12.30';
```

When I try to cast it to be a floating number

```
parseFloat('12.30'); // output is 12.3
```

I need a way for my logic to return **12.30**, the actual value, and that too a number.

Solutions I checked used,

```
parseFloat('12.30').toFixed(2);
```

but this converts it to string type and that's not acceptable in my scenario.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: 12.3 is **exactly the same value** as 12.30.

Comment: numerically `12.3` is `12.30`, they are the same value. Unless needing to print it somewhere the trailing zero is meaningless

Comment: Values are exactly the same, just if there's anyway to keep the trailing zeros.

Comment: What is your scenario that using string to display trailing zeros won't work?

Comment: `12.3` is a numerical value stored as ones and zeroes. The format in which it is stored doesn't care about how tailing decimal zeroes because they're insignificant. It doesn't care about how it looked like as a decimal string. Why do you need this tailing 0 in a number format anyway? Math doesn't care about it.

Comment: In the actual internal representation (binary floating point), trailing decimal zeros are not represented at all; it doesn't really make sense. The only time it matters is for presentation, and that can involve formatted numbers as strings.

Comment: It's just from a UX perspective that is very hard to explain to the Business from technical perspective :)

Comment: Your business people do not know the difference between a string and a number.

Comment: They understand that, but expect any number entered to be visualized exactly thee same way, eve though 12.3 and 12.30 is same Mathematically :(

Comment: If it's just for user experience why isn't a string enough?

Comment: It's an input field where masking's being used to accept only numbers

Comment: @Abhishek That doesn't explain why it needs to be of a numeric type. Masking works fine with strings and you can validate strings on whether they are valid numbers or not without converting them to a number type.

Comment: If you need to remember what the user entered, then you need a string of characters, not a number. It is up to you to design your software to record the data you need, so, if you are working on some UI that needs to receive data from the user and show it to them in the same form, you need to design your software to use strings. Using a number data type is the wrong design. Neither “12.3” nor “12.30” are numbers; they are numerals, which are strings of characters that represent numbers. A number is an abstract mathematical entity; akin to a point on a line. It does not have trailing zeros.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the detailed insight. @EricPostpischil I get what needs to be done here now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `parseFloat()`'s fault. Numerically speaking, `12.30` equals `12.3`, even if you don't use `parseFloat()`:

```js
const x = 12.30;
console.log(x); // Prints "12.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use unary plus from [Type Conversions](https://javascript.info/type-conversions) in JavaScript for get number value

```
var value = '12.30';
alert(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));         // 12.30
alert(typeof +parseFloat(value).toFixed(2)); // number
```

Get new successess in development!